# SEO. Копия постов на поддомены. Какой метатег использовать?

Tags: html5, seo, google-analytics

Есть сайт с постами по регионам. 
Посты пишутся как для своего региона так и есть возможность сделать дубль поста на другой регион.
Пост именно дублируются на другой регион вместе с контентом в отдельную папку, так как может быть подправлен текст.

Вопрос - нужно ли указывать какой либо метатег, так как по факту есть один оригинал и другие копии. canonical тег наверное не подходит, так как текст чуток может отличатся.

Answer (score 0):

Google:

> Локализованные версии страницы считаются **дубликатами**, только если основной контент остается непереведенным.
>
> Google может найти альтернативные версии ваших страниц, даже если вы
> не предпримете никаких действий, но все же желательно указывать их
> явно.   ...когда мы рекомендуем указывать альтернативные страницы:
>
> Вы перевели только шаблон веб-страницы (например, панель навигации и
> нижний колонтитул), а основной контент остался на исходном языке.
> Обычно так делается на страницах, контент которых создается
> пользователями (например, сообщения на форумах).
>
> На сайте **представлен контент на одном языке**, однако он **немного
> различается** в зависимости от региона. Так, контент на английском языке
> может быть предназначен для пользователей из Великобритании, Ирландии
> и США.
>
> Контент сайта полностью переведен на несколько языков. Например, если
> у каждой страницы есть версии на немецком и английском языках.

1. [Как использовать атрибут hreflang или файлов Sitemap для страниц на других языках и для других регионов](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077)
2. [Дубликат: Как указать каноническую страницу из числа одинаковых или похожих](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)

Яндекс:

> Если у вашей организации есть несколько региональных представительств,
> укажите на сайте адреса и телефоны каждого из них. В результате сайту
> может быть присвоено несколько регионов. Также вы можете использовать
> поддомены. Это позволит посетителю увидеть связь между основным сайтом
> и региональным.
>
> **Внимание**. Размещайте на поддомене **контент отличный** от
> содержимого основного домена. Если содержимое будет **полностью
> дублироваться или незначительно различаться**, то один из адресов будет
> **признан неглавным зеркалом** другого. Таким образом, роботы Яндекса
> начнут воспринимать два сайта как один. В результате сайт, признанный
> неглавным зеркалом, перестанет участвовать в результатах поиска.

[Региональность](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/site-geography/site-region.html)

> **Как присвоить несколько регионов**
>
> Как правильно, можно присвоить только один регион. В Вебмастере может
> отображаться несколько регионов для сайта, который был размещен в
> Яндекс.Каталоге.
>
> Регион присваивается на основании фактического адреса компании,
> указанного на сайте. Если у вашей компании есть офисы в нескольких
> регионах, посмотрите рекомендации по выбору региона. Также вы можете
> добавить сайт в Яндекс.Справочник — так регион будет присвоен
> автоматически. Как использовать региональность для поддоменов
>
> Посмотрите рекомендации по оформлению поддоменов, чтобы алгоритмы
> Яндекса правильно учли регион. Также посмотрите раздел Индексирование
> поддоменов. Как регион влияет на ранжирование сайта в результатах
> поиска
>
> Присвоенный регион является только одним из факторов, которые влияют
> на ранжирование сайта по запросам из разных регионов. Принадлежность к
> определенному региону не исключает сайт из поиска в других регионах —
> он может быть найден из любого региона, если будет релевантен запросу.
>
> Если ваш сайт долгое время не может занять желаемые позиции в поиске,
> ознакомьтесь с рекомендациями в разделе Как улучшить позиции сайта в
> поиске.

Answer (score 0):

Если главная тема дублируется, то может быть полезным использовать мета канонический линк для обозначения канонической версии.

> текст чуток может отличатся

В какой то момент поисковые системы поймут что основная тема дублирована и это может создать так называемую каннибализацию ключевых слов, то есть поисковики не смогут четко определить какое содержание и какой веб-страницы является релевантным для поискового запроса, и в результате будут игнорировать все ваши дублированные веб-страницы.

Однако я хотел бы обратить ваше внимание на тот факт, что создание дублированного содержания не имеет смысла в веб-поиске. Если даже вы создадите правильные канонические мета ссылки, то не канонические веб-страницы могут оказаться просто "мертвым грузом". Кроме того создание дублированного содержания увеличивает объем вашей работы и повышает риск совершения ошибок - однообразная работа дублирования притупляет внимание.

По моему скромному мнению, вам надо определить уникальные ключевые точки (в маркетинге это называется **[уникальным торговым предложением](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)**) характерными для каждого региона. Можно на сто процентов утверждать что на нашей планете нет двух одинаковых регионов. Далее вы можете создавать уникальное содержание для каждого региона основанное на найденных различиях между регионами. Однако, вероятно, это уже за рамками вашего вопроса.